# My VM Webserver won't boot after a power outage, how can I fix it?

Tags: server, grub2, vmware

I run a webserver on a VM of Ubuntu Server that is on a Windows Server. Recently there was a power outage and now the Ubuntu won't boot and I get error messages.[image: Error messages] The VM is managed by an IT company but they have given me access to the VM Ware management console but I have no physical access to the server.

What is my best approach to fix the file system and get it booting again? I have tried recovery from the Grub menu and also tried fsck from the minimal bash but it is not there.The solutions I see involve a physical live distro and running fsck from there. How can I do something like this remotely through the management console? Thank you in advance for any help with this...